# How to define two primary keys in an hbm

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table with two primary keys,how can i map the same in hbm mapping file.How to define two primary keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two primary keys? You probably mean a composite primary key. Check [this here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid).